# Jquery: Dynamically load set of images

Tags: jquery, html, dom, optimization, dynamic

**Context:** I am developing a company website in Phases due to launch deadline. Phase 1 is to develop the site's front-end and "hard-code" all content. Phase 2, post-launch, is to integrate developed site into a CMS back-end, wordpress, to handle present and future content.

**Situation:** During Phase 1 development I have developed a Team Carousel section on a page. This carousel will house about 35 individual employees headshots/images.

**Expected Behavior:** I would like to utilize jQuery, if possible, to dynamically build and add these individual employee images and append them into the `.carousel-item div`. Rather than hard-coding it into the HTML.

**My Concerns:** Hard-coding individual images within the HTML would hinder performance, speed and optimization, causing the site to become bloated, and ultimately leadings to too many server requests.

**Theory:** Utilizing jQuery would have a positive effect on Speed and Optimization because it would allow the page to build the HTML structure and content first, then CSS, and finally the JS.

I've utilized this function to dynamically load background-imgs on full screen sections/divs, rather than creating individual classes or inline-ing the style within the HTML

```
// Dynamic BG Images
$('.bg-img').each(function() {
    var page = $(this).attr('data-page');
    var section = $(this).attr('data-section');
    var style = {
        'background': 'url(assets/bg-imgs/' + page + '-' + section + '.jpg) center right no-repeat',
        'background-size': 'cover'
    }

    // Runs BG IMG Function
    $(this).css(style);
});

//Example utilization of function in HTML
<div data-page="careers" data-section="about" class="bg-img">
  <div class="row>">
    <div">
      <h3>In Synch</h3>
      <p><!--content--></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Questions:**

1. Can the same approach, or similar, be used for "Dynamic Image"
   population, or is it even possible to utilize jQuery in this scenario?
2. Can images be dynamically added from a directory without the use of a database, say a directory in the site root `./assets/headshots` etc.?
3. Is utilizing jQuery in this scenario better for speed and optimization vs. hard-coding images directly into HTML structure.
4. Am I in a situation where I would have to work with server-side language to accomplish this?

***Am looking for some insight before committing to full development.***

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. You can dynamically create image tags, something like this:

   `$("<img/>").attr("src", url).wrap("<p/>").appendTo(".row > div > div");`
2. Javascript has no way of reading files from a directory unless you tell it how. You will need to hard code the number of images and load them logically, or you will need a way to communicate the image names to the Javascript.
3. JQuery is slower because it won't start loading the images until the page is rendered. I personally would not recommend it, but many organizations decide the tradeoff is worth it.
4. Probably. I think this is the same as question 2. Your approach will differ, but I would recommend something like this:

   `<input type="hidden" id="myImageNames" value="image1.ext|image2.ext|..." />`

PS. Background images are generally not accessibility compliant. See http://www.ssbbartgroup.com/blog/css-background-images-and-accessibility/.